# PRS-T2 very slow with some PDFs

Tags: pdf, calibre, libreoffice

I have a PRS-T2 and use it a lot. Sometimes I convert documents to PDF in LibreOffice, then upload them to the ereader (using Calibre on a Mac). It works, but quite often turning a page can take longer than a minute. Going back a page is more often problematic. Yesterday I got a black screen and I had to restart the reader.

Most of these documents only have text, some have pictures or tables, which turns out to be more problematic. What is the best way to get these documents working properly on the reader?

Comment: PDF is the worst possible ebook format. If you have a structured source file you should _never_ convert to PDF. Even Microsoft Word format is better suited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should consider converting these to EPUB files instead of PDF. My experience with Sony is that the EPUB files are handled much better (and faster).

You can use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert DOCX, ODT and RTF formats directly, if you have the files in some other format you can use LibreOffice to convert them first to DOCX (make sure you have an up-to-date version of Calibre, older versions only supported RTF).

Another alternative is to use [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for conversion from DOCX or ODT, but you would have to try to make sure if images are correctly converted.

Comment: It took a while, but I recreated a long PDF (of which I didn't have the source) with many pictures in Libreoffice Writer, then used Calibre to create an EPUB. It took several hours to get this done, but I think it's worth the effort. The speed is good now!